# Structuring of Redux state objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am new to redux,And I am quite stuck while designing the shape of the redux state.My current part of redux state looks like this

**Invite reducer:**

```
invitees: [{
    '_id': '626262',
    'name': 'xyz'
}, {
    '_id': '6262',
    'name': 'jsjsj'
}, {
    '_id': '626',
    'name': 'gdgdg'
}
....
]
```

Should I keep this object like this or should I keep out the id's and make that as a key like:

```
invitees: [626262: {
    'name': 'xyz'
}, 6262: {
    'name': 'jsjsj'
}....]
```

If I have to go with the second option,how can I do this?? I have read in few blogs which says second option would be helpful.

Comment: Your second example is not valid JavaScript. Also, please edit your question to use code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform your array of responses to what you want by using [Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [Object Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

```
const data = [
    { id: 1, name: 'name-1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'name-2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'name-3' },
    { id: 4, name: 'name-4' },
    { id: 5, name: 'name-5' }
];

function myReducer({ payload }) {
    return payload.reduce((acc, current) => {
        return Object.assign({}, acc, {
            [current.id]: {
                [current.name]: current.name
            }
        })
    }, {});
}


const newState = myReducer({ payload: data });

console.log(newState);
/**
{
   1: { name: 'name-1' }
   2: { name: 'name-2' }
   3: { name: 'name-3' }
   4: { name: 'name-4' }
   5: { name: 'name-5' }
}
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You second example is not a valid javascript object. What you need in the second example is not an array but rather an object like

```
invitees: {
    '626262': {
       'name': 'xyz'
    }, 
    '6262': {
       'name': 'jsjsj'
    }
    ....
}
```

The second exmaple helps you in a sense that in order to get a name attribute you don't have to loop though each and every element of the array to search for the id rather you can direclty access it with the `brackets` notation

Example

```
return Object.assign({}, state, {
    [id]: {
        name: 'abc'
    }
})
```